# Parsing XML Processing Instruction

Tags: xml, parsing, processing-instruction

I'm trying to parse the `xmlts20130923/xmlconf/xmltest/valid/sa/017a.xml` file from the [XML W3C Conformance Test Suite 20130923](https://www.w3.org/XML/Test/):

```xml
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ELEMENT doc (#PCDATA)>
]>
<doc><?pi some data ? > <??></doc>
```

[Processing Instructions Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-pi)

I think the the parsed processing instruction should be `data: "some data ? > <?"` because the "first" processing instruction isn't closed due to the whitespace. Is this a correct assumption or are there two processing instructions of which the second would have no target and no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's assumtion is correct. PI content is `some data ? > <?`

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("tmp.xml")
pi = tree.xpath('//processing-instruction()')
pi[0].text
'some data ? > <?'
```